# Button view disappears when the scrollView expands

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, scrollview

In the `xml` file posted below I wanted the `scrollView` to be above the `button`, and the `Button` does not disappear no matter how the `scrollView` expands. I tried to do so as mentioned in the posted `xml` file but the problem is when the `scrollView` expands the button disappear.

please let me know what i am missing.

**XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"  
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">

     <ScrollView 
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">

         <RelativeLayout 
             android:layout_width="match_parent" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/tv_00" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

         </RelativeLayout>

     </ScrollView>

     <RelativeLayout 
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

         <Button 
             android:id="@+id/btn_00" 
             android:text="OrientierungsPruefung" 
             android:layout_width="match_parent" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

     </RelativeLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: button?  what button?

Comment: @pskink i do not know why the rest of the xml does nt wnat to show in the post. i am trying to edit

Comment: @pskink i think now the rest of the xml appears, i do not know what was the problem.

Comment: @LetsAmrIt Please put more effort in formating your code properly. This way it's easier to read for everyone!

Comment: @haywire i appreciate your advice, but i tried to well-format the xml file, but every time i do and post it, the code got truncated at certain point, dont know why

Comment: @LetsAmrIt Do your editing in Notepad++ and than C&P. Did you read my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView" />

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_00"
        android:text="OrientierungsPruefung"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Your RelativLayouts were unecessary!
The Button at the bottom will always be shown no matter the contents of the ScrollView. Key is to set layout_weight=1!

Comment: usually you don't ask for upvotes, because it's the decision of the voter whether the question is sophisticated enough for an upvote or not, but in this case, since I  had the same problems like you in the beginning (but managed to solve them myself with trying) have my upvote!

Comment: @WilliMentzel Why setting layout_weight to 1 for ScrollView works? Button has no layout_weight assigned so I would expect it not to be shown at all.